# how do i write newlines into a text box in C#

Tags: c#

So from what i understand i need to use

```
enviroment.newline
```

something like that, thought i don't thoroughly understand.
this is where i specifically need help:
I have a char array that looks something like this: {'x','x','x'} 
now lets say i want to print this into a textbox multiple times so it looks like this:

xxx
xxx
xxx

so what i did is add '\n' to the end of the array, and obviously that didn't work out very well. what character do i need to add to the array so that when i print it, it will go down a line after each print?

when i mean print i mean this:

```
textBox1.Text+= new string(chararray);
```

Comment: Is your textbox a multiline textbox?

Comment: Go to the text box in the design view. Then check the "Multi Line" box and it will work.

Comment: You must provide a bit of more code to get help.

Comment: It is multilined and Thomas answered my question!

Comment: @Bodokh If so, please accept post as an answer

Answer (score 2):

Using `\n` on Windows doesn't help, you need to use `\r\n` or `Environment.Newline` as stated by you, so you could do it in two lines

```
textBox1.Text+= new string(chararray);
textBox1.Text+= Environment.NewLine;
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your textbox is multiline-enabled:

```
char[] charArray = { 'x', 'x', 'x' };

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (char c in charArray)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
            textBox.Text += c;

        textBox.Text += Environment.NewLine;
     }
}
```

That will output:

```
xxx
xxx
xxx
```

If your textbox is not set to multiline via the properties panel in the designer as stated in the comments, add it in the code behind:

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    textBox.Multiline = true;
    textBox.Width = 400;
    textBox.Height = 300;
}
```

If your char array contained [a,b,c]:

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     foreach (char c in charArray)
     {
         textBox.Text += new string(c, 3) + Environment.NewLine;
     }
 }
```

Comment: Very weird logic to add one Newline per character in the char array and repeat each character 3 times. Replace { 'x', 'x', 'x' } by { 'a', 'b', 'c' } to see what happens.

Comment: @ThomasW. It actually answers the question. Look @ this, what author wrote:  I have a char array that looks something like this: {'x','x','x'}

Comment: @SOReader: yes, but the author also does a `new string(chararray)` and not a `new string repeat 3 times first character`

Comment: @ThomasW, easy fix. I used one of the string overloads instead of the nasty `for` loop :)

Comment: @pcnThird: still not: the author wanted `new string(chararray)`, so it should be `for (int i=0;i<3;i++) { textbox3.Text += new string(chararray) + Environment.Newline;}` which prints abc, abc, abc instead of aaa, bbb, ccc

Comment: @ThomasW., the author used the same character `x` in his post. It was rather confusing to understand what he meant. It's unusual to see a thing `x` refer  to different things in the same context.